# Year on Linda McFly's sweatshirt

Tags: back-to-the-future

I seem to remember that Linda McFly's sweatshirt (in the vacation photo) sometimes says 1984 and sometimes another year (1991?). I don't have a screencap and I can't find anything about it online. Is it like that or was I seeing things?

Comment: Not that this is conclusive, but maybe it *is* simply because they seemed alike? [The 84 resembles 91](http://www.nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Back-to-the-Future-Disappearing-Family-Photo-via-ManCaveStore.jpg) a bit from the right distance.

Answer (score 4):

[Futurepedia](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Linda_McFly) says that she *did* graduate from Hill Valley High School in 1984.

Regarding the actual photograph, see it [here](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/bttf/images/0/06/Erasedfromexistance.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070614134919) with Craig vanished.  It's a little bit clearer and looks a little more like '84'

Bear in mind that it *can't* be '91', because quite simply that Marty came from 1985 - how could he have a photograph of his sister wearing a sweatshirt with 'Class of 91' if he was only from 1985!

Comment: I can think of one way, although it's a bit farfetched...

Comment: People commonly get sweatshirts, etc that say "Class of ..." a year that is 4 years into the future, because that is the year when they will eventually graduate.

Comment: I always thought M J Fox was making a reference to the movie "class of 1984" since he did have a small part in the movie.  Linda's shirt says class of '84. Marty says "class of NINETEEN eighty four."  Just an observation.

Comment: @JoelFan considering the article I link to also states that in 1985 she is 19 years old, it's reasonable to think that the previous year she had graduated at age 18